# How to change Spring version in Grails project?

Tags: spring, grails, version

what is "the correct" way to change the spring version used by my Grails project? Latest version bundles spring 3.1.0 and I would like to know how can I change it to latest (3.1.2) ?

Is manual adding of particular dependencies to BuildConfig.groovy the only way?

Comment: Spring is so tightly coupled with Grails I'd fear this is a bad idea, in general.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can modify the BuildConfig.groovy.  But as @Gregg mentioned, I would not do it :)  Grails is tested with a specific version of spring, and you make get some unexpected results and behavior if you upgrade spring.

Do at your own risk!

Comment: I suggest, before simply changing spring version in BuildConfig, at least running grails own test suite against the new spring version. That should offer a great insight into the impact of such drastic change.

Comment: @Raphael good suggestion, but something may still fall through the cracks.  You may need to look at the code changes and make sure that the spring code changes are covered by the grails test suite.